# How to pass conditional props to unknown type of react component in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this components:

```
export function Hover(props: PolygonProps) {
   //...
}

 export function Route(props: CenterProps) {
   //...
 }
```

This enum:

```
export enum Highlight {
     HOVER,
     ROUTE,
 }
```

This object:

```
export const HIGHLIGHTS = {
    [Highlight.HOVER]: Hover,
    [Highlight.ROUTE]: Route,
};
```

And this code in render:

```
   let HighlightComponent;
   сonst center = props.center;
   const points = props.points;
   if (highlight !== undefined) {
       HighlightComponent = HIGHLIGHTS[highlight] as React.ComponentType<CenterProps | PolygonProps>;
   }
   const centerProps: CenterProps = { center };
   const polygonProps: PolygonProps = { points };

   return <div>{HighlightComponent && <HighlightComponent />}</div>
```

Question: how to pass props of needed type (CenterProps or PolygonProps) if i dont know type?
Is it correct structure for the case or not?

Comment: Where do your props come from? You know the props are `CenterProps` or `PolygonProps`. So let's say you have `const someProps: CenterProps | PolygonProps = ...`, then you can pass them like this: `<HighlightComponent {...someProps} />`

Comment: @sroes, i've updated the question.
Yes, but i don't want to pass props that have not to be passed, i can pass every prop, but it doesn't look clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two seperate props, you must still check to see which one to use. So I would drop the HIGHLIGHTS constant and simply use a switch:

```
   const centerProps: CenterProps = { center: 'someValue' };
   const polygonProps: PolygonProps = { points: 'someOtherValue' };

   let highlightComponent;
   if (highlight !== undefined) {
       switch (highlight) {
           case Highlight.HOVER:
               highlightComponent = <Hover {...polygonProps} />;
               break;
           case Highlight.ROUTE:
               highlightComponent = <Route {...centerProps} />;
               break;
       }
   }

   return <div>{highlightComponent}</div>
```

Another option would be to define the props like this:

```
const centerProps: CenterProps = { center: 'someValue' };
const polygonProps: PolygonProps = { points: 'someOtherValue' };

export const HIGHLIGHT_PROPS = {
    [Highlight.HOVER]: polygonProps,
    [Highlight.ROUTE]: centerProps,
};
```

And then:

```
let HighlightComponent;
let highlightProps;
if (highlight !== undefined) {
    HighlightComponent = HIGHLIGHTS[highlight] as React.ComponentType<CenterProps | PolygonProps>;
    highlightProps = HIGHLIGHT_PROPS[highlight] as CenterProps | PolygonProps;
}

return <div>{HighlightComponent && <HighlightComponent {...highlightProps} />}</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty sad answer, because i really don't like switch-case in render.

Comment: I will use switch-case, thank you for the answer, i though there is another way to do that without switch-case, because enum values count will increase.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you can simply do:

```
if (highlight !== undefined) {
    HighlightComponent = HIGHLIGHTS[highlight] === HIGHLIGHTS.HOVER 
       ? <Hover {...polygonProps}/>
       : <Route {...centerProps}/>;
}

return <div>{HighlightComponent && <HighlightComponent />}</div>
```

However this looks like a code smell so I would suggest that you change your props to be `HighlightComponent: JSX.Element` and just pass in the relevant component.

Comment: I have enum value (highlight) in redux store so i can't pass component with props.